# Android SDK Manager: failed to create SD card

Tags: android, ubuntu, 64-bit

I'm running Ubuntu 64-bit version 11.04, with Eclipse Linux 64-bit edition.
The Android SDK Manager is unable to create SD cards of any size.  The usual problem is that the ia32-libs are missing, and its a quick fix to install them.  However, this is not the case:

```
thomas@thomas-ubuntu:~/Documents/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
[sudo] password for thomas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ia32-libs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I definitely have those installed.  Any other ideas on this issue?

Comment: I am running natty 64 bit, too and eclipse from the repo. Everything works fine with me, so I doubt it is eclipse or missing libs. File permissions? HDD full? HDD broken? Sometimes the most simple solutions are the ones we don't manage to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to narrow down what is wrong by a process of elimination.

Try creating a file like this from the command line:

dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/username/test64MB bs=1024 count=65536

With /home/username/test64MB being a test filename (in the directory you will create the SD card in) and the count being whatever you want it to be (the one in this case creates a 64MB file).

Do an ls -l of the file, and also do an "od /home/username/test64MB".  The ls -l should show a file about 64MB created, and the od should show

```
0000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
400000000
```

That has nothing to do with Android, it is just seeing if you have the permissions, the hard drive space and so forth to create a 64 MB file in whichever directory you specify.  So if that is all OK, you know you have no problem creating 64MB files in that directory with your permissions etc.  Through a process of elimination, you've eliminated maybe half of the reasons there may have been a problem.  If you can not do the above, the problem is not Android or mksdcard, it is with something else like drive space, your permissions to write to directories or whatever.  But let us assume it did work.  Now go into the tools directory and do

```
./mksdcard 64M /home/username/sdcard64M
```

If it works, good, if not, you've narrowed it down a bit of what the problem is not.  If the dd worked but the mkscard doesn't work, I would run mksdcard with gdb and that sort of thing.